# Enabling mongodb auth

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have an install of ubuntu 14.04 x64 The only thing I have done to it is fresh update and install mongodb and pritunl. Here is how I installed both

```
 $ nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse

$ nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pritunl.list
deb http://repo.pritunl.com/stable/apt trusty main

$ apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
$ apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv CF8E292A
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install pritunl mongodb-org
$ service pritunl start
```

Now I would like to enable auth on mongodb 3.0.9 for this I have used guide here
https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-setup-auth-in-mongodb-3-0-properly-86b60aeef7e8#.a1nfxsy3a

After I create the first user and I

```
 security:
    authorization: enabled
```

I run into problems I cant make any connection from the locahost here is the error I receive

```
~# mongo pritunl --port 27017 -u admin -p passwordhere --authe                                                                                            nticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/pritunl
2016-02-08T00:18:54.096-0500 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, re                                                                                            ason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-02-08T00:18:54.098-0500 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.                                                                                            0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

Or attempting to connect to admin

```
 ~# mongo admin — port 27017 -u admin -p password — authenticationDatabase admin
    MongoDB shell version: 3.0.9
    connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/admin
    2016–02–07T09:54:09.436–0500 W NETWORK Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
    2016–02–07T09:54:09.438–0500 E QUERY Error: couldn’t connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
     at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
     at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
    exception: connect failed
```

Or any other way I try and make a connection. I feel like I am missing something simple. I thought maybe I was screwing up the user creation so I have used tried using http://3t.io/mongochef/ gui to take my potential typing errors out of the user creation.

I have been fighting this for a few days and wearing google out but not getting traction. At this point I am will to pay for some help in figuring out what Im messing up but I would like to know how to fix it so I have the knowledge of how to implement basic security. I can pay with bitcoin

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

security:
authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a YAML formatted config file?

Comment: Yes since it is a fresh install of 3.0 its what was generated as the default. I added the config file to the original post

Comment: Indentation matters: indent `authorization`. Try to restart and connect. If not, please add the relevant parts of the log file.

Comment: ......Well that works. Wish I would have known that. Seems like that should be a note in the official documentation. Any rate thanks for the help if you have a bitcoin address I would like to tip for the help you have provided.

Comment: Donate to a charity organization of your choice, instead. ;)